# Crash application on appstore and some device

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Recently I launch an application for client 
client is from australia and his application launch worldwide.
while lunch all is fine
but after lunch client complaint me its crash as tap on icon,

I also test many times at development machine and some my device but its not happen , and client face continuous issue.

so far I request client to give me crash log and here is log

```
{"app_name”:”ClinetApp”,”timestamp":"2017-04-13 09:54:07.44 +1000","app_version":"3.0","slice_uuid":"48f4924c-aba5-3b2a-9eb6-53a57019ea0a","adam_id":1004235181,"build_version":"3.0.1","bundleID":"com.ClinetApp.devlo”,”share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.3.1 (14E304)","incident_id":"62DFC0FA-A945-447A-BB99-D57C2CF4A89D","name":"ClinetApp"}

Incident Identifier: 62DFC0FA-A945-447A-BB99-D57C2CF4A89D
CrashReporter Key:   c579bf80dad6599359c3ec71d6e04522448c02de
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             ClinetApp [859]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E14004D4-AA86-4E11-9E25-3C71E59BC6C6/ClinetApp.app/ClinetApp
Identifier:          com.ClinetApp.devlo
Version:             3.0.1 (3.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.ClinetApp.devlo [499]


Date/Time:           2017-04-13 09:54:07.3762 +1000
Launch Time:         2017-04-13 09:54:07.0320 +1000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.1 (14E304)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
removed

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x000000018863d014 0x18861e000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000188707334 0x188702000 + 21300
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00000001885b19c4 0x188550000 + 399812
3   libc++abi.dylib               0x000000018807d1b0 0x18807c000 + 4528
4   libc++abi.dylib               0x0000000188096c04 0x18807c000 + 109572
5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x00000001880a4820 0x18809c000 + 34848
6   libc++abi.dylib               0x00000001880935d4 0x18807c000 + 95700
7   libc++abi.dylib               0x00000001880931a8 0x18807c000 + 94632
8   libobjc.A.dylib               0x00000001880a46f8 0x18809c000 + 34552
9   CoreFoundation                0x000000018951ee00 0x189516000 + 36352
10  UIKit                         0x000000018f7dc45c 0x18f762000 + 500828
11  UIKit                         0x000000018f7d7130 0x18f762000 + 479536
12  ClinetApp                      0x00000001000b4c7c 0x100038000 + 511100
13  libdyld.dylib                 0x000000018852d59c 0x188529000 + 17820

    Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000188702d78 0x188702000 + 3448

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x000000018863da88 0x18861e000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00000001887030a0 0x188702000 + 4256
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000188702d7c 0x188702000 + 3452

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000188702d78 0x188702000 + 3448

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000188702d78 0x188702000 + 3448

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x000000018861f224 0x18861e000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x000000018861f09c 0x18861e000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                0x00000001895f0e88 0x189516000 + 896648
3   CoreFoundation                0x00000001895eeadc 0x189516000 + 887516
4   CoreFoundation                0x000000018951ed94 0x189516000 + 36244
5   Foundation                    0x000000018a038d64 0x18a02c000 + 52580
6   Foundation                    0x000000018a059b34 0x18a02c000 + 187188
7   UIKit                         0x00000001901615f8 0x18f762000 + 10483192
8   Foundation                    0x000000018a1362c8 0x18a02c000 + 1090248
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x000000018870575c 0x188702000 + 14172
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x000000018870566c 0x188702000 + 13932
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000188702d84 0x188702000 + 3460

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x000000018863da88 0x18861e000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000188703274 0x188702000 + 4724
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000188702d7c 0x188702000 + 3452

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x000000018863da88 0x18861e000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000188703274 0x188702000 + 4724
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x0000000188702d7c 0x188702000 + 3452

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
removed
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

next log in image

[image]

So please help me to resolve issue..

Comment: Let me know your project deployment target and your client iphone os version?

Comment: this is the issue i am too having on development phase too. i don't know the exact issue but some time it crashes and throws the same exception as you are facing. this started happen after some libraries are added and i implement root of window changing function with animation. Please post names of library so that we can debug together.

Comment: @dip so is any POD affect on that and other library ?
in short how you overcome with that

Comment: i am not sure what is the actual cause.

Comment: Search your app for abort()

Answer (score 0):

Hello all thanks for view post and hint me

actually i have issue with date formater which i use in didLunch

i am use @"dd-MMM-yyyy, hh:mm a" pattern and i use that date string by split, so when user have 24 hours app is crash and when have 12 hours its running file,

after i solved by

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[_dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
```

Again thanks to all.